# LazyColumn with SwipeToDismiss

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

What is the correct way to use `SwipeToDismiss` and `LazyColumn` in android compose `alpha09`?

My approach:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.dp),
) {
    items(items = items) {
        TrackedActivityRecord(it.activity, it.record, scaffoldState)
    }
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun TrackedActivityRecord(
    activity: TrackedActivity,
    record: TrackedActivityRecord,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState,
    vm: TimelineVM = viewModel()
){
    val dismissState = rememberDismissState()

    if (dismissState.value != DismissValue.Default){
        LaunchedEffect(subject = activity){

            val deleted = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Awesome", "do it")

            if (deleted == SnackbarResult.Dismissed){
                vm.rep.deleteRecordById(activity.id, record.id)
            }

            dismissState.snapTo(DismissValue.Default)
        }

    }

    SwipeToDismiss(
        state = dismissState,
        background = {
            Box(Modifier.size(20.dp). background(Color.Red))
        },

    ) {
        Record(activity = activity, record = record)
    }
}
```

There a is problem when the `LazyColumn` is recomposed the item on the deleted position is `Dismissed` - not visible. I hacked it with `dismissState.snapTo(DismissValue.Default)`. But for split of a second you can see the old item visible. If I do not use remember but DismissState I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot round NaN value.` caused by `androidx.compose.material.SwipeToDismissKt$SwipeToDismiss$2$1$1$1.invoke-nOcc-ac(SwipeToDismiss.kt:244)`

Comment: I'm using the same workaround you came up with. I think this is the best solution for now, because compose is still in alpha and this will possibly not be an issue in the future anyways.

Comment: Great, I will leave it as it is for now, Thanks.

Comment: Ran into the same issue, thanks for the hack. Did you file this as an issue with Google?

Answer (score 16):

modified from https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#swipetodismiss:

```
import androidx.compose.animation.animateColorAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloatAsState
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.scale
import androidx.compose.material.DismissValue.*
import androidx.compose.material.DismissDirection.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Delete
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Done
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

// This is an example of a list of dismissible items, similar to what you would see in an
// email app. Swiping left reveals a 'delete' icon and swiping right reveals a 'done' icon.
// The background will start as grey, but once the dismiss threshold is reached, the colour
// will animate to red if you're swiping left or green if you're swiping right. When you let
// go, the item will animate out of the way if you're swiping left (like deleting an email) or
// back to its default position if you're swiping right (like marking an email as read/unread).
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun MyContent(
    items: List<ListItem>,
    dismissed: (listItem: ListItem) -> Unit
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LazyColumn {
        items(items, {listItem: ListItem -> listItem.id}) { item ->
            val dismissState = rememberDismissState()
            if (dismissState.isDismissed(EndToStart)){
                dismissed(item)
            }
            SwipeToDismiss(
                state = dismissState,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 1.dp),
                directions = setOf(StartToEnd, EndToStart),
                dismissThresholds = { direction ->
                    FractionalThreshold(if (direction == StartToEnd) 0.25f else 0.5f)
                },
                background = {
                    val direction = dismissState.dismissDirection ?: return@SwipeToDismiss
                    val color by animateColorAsState(
                        when (dismissState.targetValue) {
                            Default -> Color.LightGray
                            DismissedToEnd -> Color.Green
                            DismissedToStart -> Color.Red
                        }
                    )
                    val alignment = when (direction) {
                        StartToEnd -> Alignment.CenterStart
                        EndToStart -> Alignment.CenterEnd
                    }
                    val icon = when (direction) {
                        StartToEnd -> Icons.Default.Done
                        EndToStart -> Icons.Default.Delete
                    }
                    val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                        if (dismissState.targetValue == Default) 0.75f else 1f
                    )

                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(color)
                            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
                        contentAlignment = alignment
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            icon,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description",
                            modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                        )
                    }
                },
                dismissContent = {
                    Card(
                        elevation = animateDpAsState(
                            if (dismissState.dismissDirection != null) 4.dp else 0.dp
                        ).value
                    ) {
                        Text(item.text)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
    
data class ListItem(val id:String, val text:String)
```

The main problem in the original is that the dismiss-state is remembered by the item's position. When the list changes (which is quite obvious when deleting an item), the remembered dismissState will then apply to the next item (which is wrong of course). To remedy this use items(items, {listItem: MyRoutesViewModel.ListItem -> listItem.id} ) instead of just items(items)

Comment: Hi, so I was having the same problem as you described and what you said makes total sense. I'm trying to do the same thing but I cannot figure out how. I have a list: List<Pair<Int, Pairing>> where the first item in every pair is the id. So I wrote items(list, { pair: Pair<Int, Pairing> -> pair.first } but I get a "Required: ((Int) -> Any)? Found: Pair<Int, Pairing> -> Any". I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem! Lorenzo in your case I think you should be able to use `items(list.size, { index -> list[index].first }) { index -> }`.

Answer (score 9):

Here you can find an example of how to use LazyColumn with SwipeToDismiss:

```
// This is an example of a list of dismissible items, similar to what you would see in an
// email app. Swiping left reveals a 'delete' icon and swiping right reveals a 'done' icon.
// The background will start as grey, but once the dismiss threshold is reached, the colour
// will animate to red if you're swiping left or green if you're swiping right. When you let
// go, the item will animate out of the way if you're swiping left (like deleting an email) or
// back to its default position if you're swiping right (like marking an email as read/unread).
LazyColumn {
    items(items) { item ->
        var unread by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
            confirmStateChange = {
                if (it == DismissedToEnd) unread = !unread
                it != DismissedToEnd
            }
        )
        SwipeToDismiss(
            state = dismissState,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 4.dp),
            directions = setOf(StartToEnd, EndToStart),
            dismissThresholds = { direction ->
                FractionalThreshold(if (direction == StartToEnd) 0.25f else 0.5f)
            },
            background = {
                val direction = dismissState.dismissDirection ?: return@SwipeToDismiss
                val color by animateColorAsState(
                    when (dismissState.targetValue) {
                        Default -> Color.LightGray
                        DismissedToEnd -> Color.Green
                        DismissedToStart -> Color.Red
                    }
                )
                val alignment = when (direction) {
                    StartToEnd -> Alignment.CenterStart
                    EndToStart -> Alignment.CenterEnd
                }
                val icon = when (direction) {
                    StartToEnd -> Icons.Default.Done
                    EndToStart -> Icons.Default.Delete
                }
                val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                    if (dismissState.targetValue == Default) 0.75f else 1f
                )

                Box(
                    Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color).padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
                    contentAlignment = alignment
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        icon,
                        contentDescription = "Localized description",
                        modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                    )
                }
            },
            dismissContent = {
                Card(
                    elevation = animateDpAsState(
                        if (dismissState.dismissDirection != null) 4.dp else 0.dp
                    ).value
                ) {
                    ListItem(
                        text = {
                            Text(item, fontWeight = if (unread) FontWeight.Bold else null)
                        },
                        secondaryText = { Text("Swipe me left or right!") }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#swipetodismiss

Comment: Am I the only one for who this example only works until list is changed? I implemented this solution but when I delete an item, swipe on all the other items below it stops working.

Comment: @PrimožIvančič I have a similar (same?) problem. It seems like the whole composable is tied to the POSITION of the list, and not the ITEM. If I dismiss the top item, the next item takes its place but remains in the dismissed state.

Comment: Yes @GustavKarlsson, this is the same issue. 
FYI: I was not able to get around the issue, so I abandoned the 'swipe to dismiss' idea and implemented a button.

Answer (score 7):

Try to pass the key inside lazy column. Then rememberDismissState will work according to the item id instead of the list position.

```
 LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Background)
                        .padding(bottom = SpaceLarge + 20.dp),
                    state = bottomListScrollState
                ) {
                    if (newsList.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                        items(
                            items = newsList.value,
                           // Apply the key like below
                            key = { news -> news.url },
                            itemContent = { news ->
                                var isDeleted by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                                val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
                                    confirmStateChange = {
                                        Timber.d("dismiss value ${it.name}")
                                        if (it == DismissValue.DismissedToEnd) isDeleted =
                                            !isDeleted
                                        else if (it == DismissValue.DismissedToStart) isDeleted =
                                            !isDeleted
                                        it != DismissValue.DismissedToStart || it != DismissValue.DismissedToEnd
                                    }
                                )
                                SwipeToDismiss(
                                    state = dismissState,
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 2.dp),
                                    directions = setOf(
                                        DismissDirection.StartToEnd,
                                        DismissDirection.EndToStart
                                    ),
                                    dismissThresholds = { direction ->
                                        FractionalThreshold(if (direction == DismissDirection.StartToEnd) 0.25f else 0.5f)
                                    },
                                    background = {
                                        val direction =
                                            dismissState.dismissDirection ?: return@SwipeToDismiss
                                        val color by animateColorAsState(
                                            when (dismissState.targetValue) {
                                                DismissValue.Default -> Color.LightGray
                                                DismissValue.DismissedToEnd -> Color.Red
                                                DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> Color.Red
                                            }
                                        )
                                        val alignment = when (direction) {
                                            DismissDirection.StartToEnd -> Alignment.CenterStart
                                            DismissDirection.EndToStart -> Alignment.CenterEnd
                                        }
                                        val icon = when (direction) {
                                            DismissDirection.StartToEnd -> Icons.Default.Delete
                                            DismissDirection.EndToStart -> Icons.Default.Delete
                                        }
                                        val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                                            if (dismissState.targetValue == DismissValue.Default) 0.75f else 1f
                                        )
                                        Box(
                                            Modifier
                                                .fillMaxSize()
                                                .background(color)
                                                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp),
                                            contentAlignment = alignment
                                        ) {
                                            Icon(
                                                icon,
                                                contentDescription = "Localized description",
                                                modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }, dismissContent = {
                                        if (isDeleted) {
                                            viewModel.deleteNews(news)
                                            Timber.d("Deleted ${news.url}")
                                            snackbarController.getScope().launch {
                                                snackbarController.showSnackbar(
                                                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                                                    message = "Article successfully Deleted",
                                                    actionLabel = "Undo"
                                                )
                                                viewModel.result = news
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            NewsColumnItem(news = news) {
                                                viewModel.result = news
                                                actions.gotoNewsViewScreen(news.url.encode())
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            })

                    }
                }
```

Comment: This works, but what do I do if I can't use LazyList? What if I have a Column with a for loop going through the items instead?

Comment: Calling `viewModel.deleteNews(news)` as part of the recomposition cannot possibly be correct. Please revise that Side-Effects in a Composable happen only in DisposableEffect or LaunchedEffect blocks with the correct key (in your case, most likely `Unit`). Don't use `SideEffect` because that's actually not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers have mentioned passing a key factory to a `LazyColumn` in order to tie the state of a list item to a unique identifier rather than its position in the list. If for whatever reason you can't use a `LazyColumn`, you can still use the `key` utility like this:

```kotlin
for (item in items) {
  key(item.id) {
    ... // use item
  }
}
```

Solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70191854/8124931