# Use item keys in non-lazy Column

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

`LazyColumn` has [item keys](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys), in order to tie the item's state to a unique identifier rather than the list index. Is there a way to use item keys in a non-lazy list like this one?

```kotlin
Column {
  for (item in list) {
    Text(item)
  }
}
```

The reason I ask is because I want to implement `SwipeToDismiss` to delete items from a list, which only works if you pass a key to a `LazyColumn` ([solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68314565/8124931)), but my list of dismissable items is nested inside of a `LazyColumn`, and I can't nest a `LazyColumn` inside of another `LazyColumn`'s itemContent block (Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts is not allowed):

```
val items = listOf<String>(...)
val groups = items.groupBy { it.first() }

LazyColumn {
  items(groups, { /* key */ }) { (firstChar, group) ->
    // not allowed!
    LazyColumn {
      items(group, { /* key */ }) { item ->
        Text(item)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I could wrap the `items()` call itself in a for loop like this:

```kotlin
val items = listOf<String>(...)
val groups = items.groupBy { it.first() }

LazyColumn {
  groups.forEach { (firstChar, group) ->
    items(group, { /* key */ }) { item ->
      Text(item)
    }
  }
}
```

But then state in each of the outer loop's items would be keyed against its index. And I need to provide item keys for groups as well, in order to preserve their state on position changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The general pattern for this is,

```
for (item in items) {
  key(item) {
    ... // use item
  }
}
```

The `key` composable is special and Compose will use `item` as a key to detect when the state should move when an the value of `item` moves in the `items` collection.

Comment: Unrelated to this specific question, but this is the answer to a problem I had where removal of items in a custom layout would suddenly use the wrong remember animation values if I removed a repeated composable.  I figured out it was getting confused and probably needed a key like lazy columns!  Thank you!