# animateFloatAsState in compose custom layout not animating all composables

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom layout which is a calendar like screen that the user can drag around as a whole. Events that are visible to the user in the time frame visible on the screen get drawn with placeables/measurable.

I have a feature that as the user partially drags events off screen, the titles in the content sticky to the top of the event until it's fully dragged off screen.

When this happens, I add a little image up top to indicate the event continues above it

E.g

```
"Event Name"
```

turns into

```
^
"Event Name"
```

I want to animate the "Event Name" text moving down as the ^ appears or disappears instead of it simply jumping down when I insert/remove the ^ on recomposition.

It looked like this is what I needed to animate the text properly

```
@Composable
fun TestItem(event: Event) {
    val offset: Float by animateFloatAsState(if (event.isPartiallyOffScreen)) 100f else 0f)

    Box(Modifier.background(color=event.color)) {
        Text(
            text = event.name,
            modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer(
                translationY = offset
            )
         )
    }
}
```

And this does indeed animate the text smoothly downward and upward as the content switches between on/off screen, the problem though, is I have dozens of these on the screen, and it only works for the first item in a column until a gap happens.

E.g

[image]

Event 811 will animate the text down as it goes off screen, as Event 195 starts going off screen it just jumps from 0 to 100 the moment it happens, and then Event 757 will work and animate text properly, although after making a gif of it, 757 stutters a little too.

It's almost like because the Event 811 composable ceases to exist the moment it's fully off screen, it thinks Event 195 is Event 811 as it takes that spot in the placeable order and it's now starting to go offscreen and reuses the previous values?  By the time it reaches 757 it's been gone for many drags, and it kinda works as expected?

Update: I've since confirmed that if I stop removing items from the list if they are off screen, it works as expected on all items, but the performance hit and jank are considerable as there are upwards of 80-100 items being drawn, most off screen, so that's not really an option.

I've tried using LaunchedEffects as well with a unique key from the event, and it doesn't work either?

This is the only stateful thing in the composable, everything else is just values being set from the constructor content

I'm kind of stumped on what to do with this problem.

Comment: Please add a gif, it'll be easier to understand what's going on

Comment: @PylypDukhov Added.  195 is the one that jumps instead of animates. There's also a weird hiccup as 195 goes off screen on event 757.  It looks like it briefly thinks its 195 and stutters?

Comment: it looks like you're creating different views instead of updating a single view parameters to animate it, but it's hard to say without [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The whole screen is dozen of composables in a custom layout that are getting resized and recomposed and removed/added as things happen yes. Which is why I think it doesn't know what composable is what after it goes away.  It makes me think this isn't doable as currently designed.  I imagine the numbers to animate things down would have to originate from the VM to make it work, which isn't really doable in this set up.  This is an incredibly complex screen I'm not going to bother to try to create a MRE, it would be pointless.

Comment: Alternatively I could also try to pass enough information in that I could deterministically decide how far to offset it instead of using any animation API.   It doesn't actually have to be from the VM, it just needs to be precalculated.  As I drag, it would adjust the position, but the animation is nicer as it moves it down in 1 animated go instead of pixel by pixel slowly as I drag.

Comment: Also I just confirmed that it works if I keep recomposing content off screen instead of removing the event from the list, but that's a huge performance with hit with all sorts of jank when there's 80-100 being drawn and not seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After confirming that my screen would work if I didn't remove off screen composables, it confirmed my suspicion that the recompositions were getting confused due to the items all being the same.

I thought using keys on the animations would solve the issue, but it didn't.  What I needed was a key on the composable as described in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70191854/2408033

So for me, I needed to wrap each event in the custom layout in a `key` composable

```
 Layout(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxHeight()
    content = {
        eventList.forEach { event ->
           key(event) {
               TestItem(displayPerformance, adjustedStart)
           }
        }
    },
) { measureables, constraints ->
```